# ASP.NET Core 3 MVC custom client validation for arrays

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a bit of a weird one. I need to perform client-side validation for an array of strings but I have no idea how. The server-side validation works just fine, but each individual `<input>` doesn't have the `data-val` that I set. Anyone know how to solve this?

**Model**

```
[RequiredIf]
public string[] PaperQuantity {get;set;}
```

**View**

```
<input asp-for="PaperQuantity[count]">
```

**Custom Validation**

```
public class RequiredIfAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientModelValidator
{
  protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
  {
    // Validation method here
  }
  public void AddValidation(ClientModelValidationContext context)
  {
    MergeAttribute(context.Attributes, "data-val", "true");
    MergeAttribute(context.Attributes, "data-val-requiredif", ErrorMessage);
  }
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$.validator.addMethod("requiredif", function () {
  // Validation method here
});
$.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.addBool("requiredif");
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you using **remote validation** for these cases. You can validate whatever you want using optionally data from your DbContext and it **automatically implies** client-side validation with `jQuery Unobtrusive`.

#### Example

Annotate property with [Remote] attribute

```
[Remote(action: "VerifyPaper", controller: "MyControler")]
public string PaperQuantity {get; set;}
```

Since jQuery expects JSON response your `Verify paper` method in your controller, for example, should be like this:

```
[AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST")]
public IActionResult VerifyPaper(string paperQuantity)
{
    if (string.Empty(paperQuantity))
    {
        // Your error message
        return Json("Paper quantity can't be empty.");
    }
    // If everything is okay return true
    return Json(true);
}
```

And your view should be like this:

```
<label asp-for="PaperQuantity">Paper quantity</label>
<input asp-for="PaperQuantity"/>
<span asp-validation-for="PaperQuantity"></span>
```

You can read more about Remote validation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-3.1#remote-attribute).

Comment: Will this work with the individual values within the array? My biggest issue right now is that because the asp tag help isn't _exactly_ `PaperQuantity` (`PaperQuantity[count]`), the `data-val` tags don't get added to HTML code and JS can't recognize it. The field is basically a dynamically generated one where the user can add as many PaperQuantity fields as they want, and I need to check that at least one of them is over 0.

Comment: I'm not sure about how you dynamically generating these fields, but it is kinda real-time validation, its called whenever you change the value. If your property is an array, you can use array methods for checking like `array.Any(x => x > 0)` to check is there any value with the optional condition. Using tag helpers It should automatically add `data-val` tags.